# loading values into an array (listview) vb6?

Tags: sql, listview, vb6

I have reference table in SQL-SERVER with two column names: ID and Label. What I'm trying to do is load my values into an array and populate a listview with it. My goal is to show the LABEL values (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday...Sunday), however, when one is selected, to save it with ID (1,2,3,4,5,6,7).

Comment: This isn't a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When you add the list item to the list view you could set the text to be the label and the Tag to be the ID.  When you save the details take the value from the Tag property.  If you are using the Listbox control, then you could use the ItemData property.

Comment: Skip the pointless array and just add values from the query result (Recordset) into the ListBox which you probably really mean because a ListView would be silly.

Comment: @Bob77, don't understand why it would be silly. It's a LISTVIEW.

Comment: ListView controls are heavy and complex compared to simple ListBox/ComboBox controls and extreme overkill if you just need a "day of the week picker."